# Saving value of stack pointer in C variable in Code Composer studio for ARM cortex M4f

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I would like to know a method that can store the value of the stack pointer onto a variable in C.

Comment: Consult your C compiler's manual on how to write inline assembly that associates a register with a C variable; then copy the stack pointer into that output register.

Comment: Why? What exactly do you expect the stack pointer to point to?

Comment: TI compiler doesn't have a way of referring local variables from inline assembly: http://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/compiler/f/343/p/264539/925735#925735

Comment: We really need to know why you need it, and what compiler you are using. The most generic and standard compliant way is to declare a local and have its address taken. Of course that won't be exactly `SP` but might be close enough.

Answer (score 0):

I find inline asm to be useless as it is so compiler specific, esp for something like this just use an asm function.  for gnu assembler:

```
.thumb
.thumb_func
.globl GETSP
GETSP:
   mov r0,sp
   bx lr
```

in c

```
extern unsigned int GETSP ( void );
...
unsigned int sp;
...
sp=GETSP();
```

understand that each place you use this will give the same value every time.  for many compilers the whole function will give the same result across the function, if the function is reused by other different functions then you might get the sp value to vary.

Comment: I Think the last remark is not fully correct. `alloca`, for example, should modify the value.

Comment: not all compilers allocate a stack frame up front, it is the lazy/easy way and you see it a lot, but quite possible to have a compiler not do that and in a case like that you would also see the sp vary across a function.

Comment: i have tried to use a function pointer method in which i use a void function type and move the value of the SP into R0 using inline assembly inside of that function . Which has helped. I can manage to get value of the SP into a C variable by typecasting it afterwards.